# lua equiv of __LINE__ and __FILE__?

Tags: lua

I really like C's `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` ... does lua provide something  similar? (I find it useful for tracking down printf's ... to know which file and which line the message comes from).

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
function __FILE__() return debug.getinfo(2,'S').source end
function __LINE__() return debug.getinfo(2, 'l').currentline end
```

Untested, [credit goes here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FileLineMacros).

Comment: Note that it is generally a bad idea to name global symbols starting with double underscore. Such names are usually belong to the language implementors.

Answer (score 4):

I use something like this for getting the line number from the c side:

```
int lua_getline(lua_State* L, int level) {
    lua_Debug ar;
    lua_getstack(L, level, &ar);
    lua_getinfo(L, "l", &ar);
    return ar.currentline;
}
```

Calling [lua_getinfo](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_getinfo) with `"lS"` will additionally fill the source field of the `lua_Debug` struct -- although it may not always be a file name IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

`__LINE__` and `__FILE__` are often used together, so here's a print function that prefixes output with the file and line:

```lua
function trace(...)
  local info = debug.getinfo(2, "Sl")
  local t = info.short_src .. ":" .. info.currentline .. ": "
  print(t, ...)
end
```

Calling `trace("Hello", "world")` will give output like:

```
scripts\file.lua:68:    Hello   world
```

*(The space after the final colon ensures that this output matches the format expected by line parsing tools like vim's errorformat.)*

Alternatively, use the more clever [lume.trace](https://github.com/rxi/lume/blob/master/lume.lua#L659-L670) which prints prettier numbers and joins arguments with spaces instead of tabs.